# Show that $\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{\tan(x)}{1+\sec(x)})=\frac{1}{1+\cos(x)}$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

> Show that:
>
> $\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{\tan(x)}{1+\sec(x)})=\frac{1}{1+\cos(x)}$
>
> Applying the quotient rule I get
>
> $\frac{\sec^2(x)(1+\sec(x))-\sec(x)\tan^2(x)}{(1+\sec^2(x))}$

From here I go into many directions but not towards the RHS. Guidance is much appreciated

Comment: Do you know how to write $\sec$ and $\tan $ in terms of $\sin $ and $\cos$?

Comment: Multiply both numerator and denominator by $\cos(x)$ before differentiating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have \begin{align*}\frac{\sec^{2}x(1+\sec x)-\sec x \tan^{2}x}{(1+\sec x)^2} &= \frac{\sec x(\sec x + \sec^2 x - \tan^2x)}{(1+\sec x)^2} \qquad \text{(factoring the numerator)} \\ &= \frac{\sec x(\sec x+1)}{(1+\sec x)^2} \qquad \text{(by the identity $\tan^2 x + 1 \equiv \sec^2 x$)} \\ &= \frac{\sec x}{1+\sec x} \\ &= \frac{1}{\cos x + 1} \qquad \text{(multiplying the numerator and denominator by $\cos x$)}\end{align*} as required.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in comments it seems that the easiest way is to replace the function by terms of $\sin$ and $\cos.$ We have

$$\sec(x)=\frac 1 {\cos x}$$
$$\tan x=\frac {\sin x}{\cos x}$$

and get

$$\frac{\tan(x)}{1+\sec(x)}=\frac{\frac {\sin x}{\cos x}}{1+\frac 1 {\cos x}}=\frac{\sin x}{1+\cos x}$$

So we have 
$$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{\sin x}{1+\cos x}\\=\frac{\cos x (1+\cos x)-\sin x(-\sin x)}{(1+\cos x)^2}\\=\frac{\cos x+\cos^2x+\sin^2x}{(1+\cos x)^2}\\=\frac{1+\cos x}{(1+\cos x)^2}\\=\frac 1 {1+\cos x}$$

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify before differentiating,
$$\frac{\tan x}{1+\sec x}=\frac{\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}}{1+ \frac1{\cos x}}=\frac{\sin x}{1+\cos x}$$
$$\therefore \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{\tan x}{1+\sec x}\right)=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{\sin x}{1+\cos x}\right)$$
$$=\frac{(1+\cos x)\cos x-\sin x(-\sin x)}{(1+\cos x)^2}$$
$$=\frac{\cos x+\cos^2x+\sin^2x}{(1+\cos x)^2}$$
$$=\frac{1+\cos x}{(1+\cos x)^2}$$
$$=\frac{1}{1+\cos x}$$